# How to upload image to direct link on Android

Tags: android, image, file-upload, upload

On android

I want to uploading a image to internet

after uploaded , got it's url direct link

like.."http://sivertimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Apple_logo_black.svg_.png"

or.."http://gloucesterstage.com/_website/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/apples2.jpg"

how can i do this?

thanks

---

edit

---

I find a same case 
[Android, uploading a photo to host on imgur programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124484/android-uploading-a-photo-to-host-on-imgur-programatically)

but this method is too old to use,

many codes are deprecated

Comment: not clear what you are asking! the two pictures are different! what do you mean by direct link?

Comment: I ment the url's extension is "jpg" or "png" , not "html" or "php"